# Cannot get content on the same line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to put all the controls on the same row without using the class row 'cause this controls are near a column, that also have other controls. So my structure is actually this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <button class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            Add</button>

        <button class="btn btn-default" >
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            Remove</button>

        <button class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></span>
            Refresh</button>

        <button class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text"
                   class="form-control"
                   placeholder="Hello world">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="clear btn btn-default clean-resource btn-danger" type="button">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
  </div>
```

and this is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/28646/)

How you can see the buttons are on the same line but the textbox go ahead, I don't know wham is wrong. Someone could help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this type of grid section and http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp and adjust screen size according to this link

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4">
            <button class="btn btn-default">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                Add</button>

            <button class="btn btn-default" >
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                Remove</button>

            <button class="btn btn-default">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></span>
                Refresh</button>

            <button class="btn btn-default">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen"></span>
            </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text"
                       class="form-control"
                       placeholder="Hello world">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="clear btn btn-default clean-resource btn-danger" type="button">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```